# Importing a module from a higher directory in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, import, python-import

I'm working on a Python project and I have a folder called `Api` structure that includes various modules and a folder specifically for tests. I want to include a Python file from `api` of the project folders into a test file located in the tests folder. How can I achieve this?

```
my_project/
    ├── api/
    |     ├── core/
    │     |     ├── file1.py
    │     |     ├── file2.py
    |     |     ...
    │     ├── module3.py
    │     └── ...
    ├── tests/
    │     ├── test_my_module.py
    │     ├── ...
    └── ...
```

Image of Project :
[Directory images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQUEc.png)

My code snippet is this, but it gives me an error:

```
import unittest
from api.core import ContentGenerator





class TestMagicBox(unittest.TestCase):
    content_generator = ContentGenerator()

    def test_caption(self):
        result = TestMagicBox.content_generator.generate_description(
            "pizza", "peperoni pizza"
        )
        self.assertIsNotNone(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

My test files are located in a separate directory outside of the api folder, specifically in the tests directory. In the tests folder, I want to include and test the magic_box.py module from the core subfolder of the api project. (`api/core/magic_box.py`)

What's the recommended approach to achieve this in Python while ensuring clean and maintainable testing practices?

Your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches.
I would suggest using "pytest" which automatically discoveres and runs your tests while handline the import paths for you.

```
pip install pytest
```

another Idea which is simpler but not so good as the first one In case you have multiple tests in future:

```
import sys
import unittest

# Add the project's root directory to the Python path
sys.path.append("../")  # Adjust the path as needed to reach the root directory

from api.core import ContentGenerator

class TestMagicBox(unittest.TestCase):
    content_generator = ContentGenerator()

    def test_caption(self):
        result = TestMagicBox.content_generator.generate_description(
            "pizza", "pepperoni pizza"
        )
        self.assertIsNotNone(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, paths to module imports are relative to the directory where you run the Python interpreter, so to run modules in the `tests` package with access to modules in the `api` package, you need to run Python from their parent directory, `HERMES`, e.g.:

```
HERMES> python tests/test_content_generator.py
```

Comment: I exactly do this, and I'm in Hermes, but it doesn't work and say can't find API

Answer (score 0):

#### Case 1: Executing as a standalone python script

```
/HERMES$ python tests/test_content_generator.py
```

In this case,  modules are being looked in the directory of executed file and thus api module is not found.
As [Kiese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22221152/kiese) said you have to add following line to add path for interpreter to look for modules:

```
sys.path.append("./")
from api.core import ContentGenerator
```

#### Case 2: Executing as a Python module (preferred way)

```
HERMES$ python -m tests.test_content_generator
```

In this case, the file is executed as a module in the **top** directory and modules in this directory can be imported without any issue.

In this case, you might need to add an empty `__init__.py` file to directories, which will allow them to be discovered as modules.

Related question with detailed discussions: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

I also learned it recently, used in my project https://github.com/bhupenderbindal/sa_mvcnn

PS: I cannot say this is the standard way.